# What is this strange tea?

Tags: tea

What sort of tea is this and how is it drunk? It doesn't look like any tea I am familiar with.

[image: picture of strange tea]

Comment: Personally, I would not drink unidentified dried plants with such a label - but that’s just my opinion.

Comment: Strongly agreed with Stephie - absent any more information about where this came from and who labeled it (in which case you should probably ask them what it is) my answer to the "how to drink this" question is simply DO NOT.

Comment: I assume it's just tea, probably comes with wild claims to enhance your "life".

Comment: looks like dried flowers to me. Definitely wouldn't consume it without more information as to what it is and what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like an herbal tea, also called a tisane.

You brew it the same way as regular black tea.  Most tisanes call for a steep time of 5-10 minutes and boiling water.  Judging by the scale of the fingers, there's enough in the picture for about a cup.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like leftovers of hibiscus tea. I'm 90% sure.